# Pass variable from Ajax to PHP does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have such code

```
<form>
        <input type="text" value="" name="someval">
        <button id="ajax-button">ajaxButton</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#ajax-button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  url: "action.php",
                  data: { text : $('input[name=someval]').val() },
                  dataType: "text",
                  success: function (data){
                    alert(data);
                  }
                });         

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Now I try to echo the Ajax returned value in php.

I try

```
echo json_encode($text);
echo $text; 
echo $_GET['text'];
```

Al are wrong.

How to get it in PHP.
Thanks

Comment: Another that is important to answer yourself is this....do you want the response(data returned) to be seen instantly or on page refresh?

Comment: instantly.. without refrsh

Comment: Did you actually use the required hooks for your Ajax callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set attributes for the form to get semantic correct html

```
<form action="action.php" id="someForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" value="" name="someval">
    <select id="someSelect">
        <option value="some_1">some 1</option>
        <option value="some_2">some 2</option>
        <option value="some_3">some 3</option>
    </select>
    <button id="ajax-button">Send</button>
</form>
```

Your script

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        var form = $("#someForm"),
            select = $("#someSelect"),
            url, formData;

        form.submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            url = form.attr("action");
            formData = form.serializeArray();

            $.post(url, data, function(response){
                console.log($.parseJSON(response));
            });
        });

        select.change(function(){

           url = form.attr("action");
           formData = form.serializeArray();

           $.post(url, data, function(response){
                console.log($.parseJSON(response));
            });                   
        });

    });
</script>
```

Your php file(path to file set in action attribute of the form).

```
<?php

    var_dump($_POST);

?>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65449/discussion-on-answer-by-smile0ff-pass-variable-from-ajax-to-php-does-not-work).

Answer (score 0):

Use `data: 'text=' + $('input[name=someval]').val() ,` instead. And in PHP you can directly access it using `echo $_GET['text'];` only without the need of json encoding it.

Otherwise the syntax of json is `data: { "text" : $('input[name=someval]').val() },`.